# Working with parsed model in Xtend validator

Tags: xtext, emf, xtend, dsl-tools

I want to know how I can access the parsed model of my program. I have a validation check written in xtend which accepts a rule **A** as it parameter. however I want to search the entire parsed tree and make sure that any other reference to this specific instance of **A** follows certain specifications.

```
@Check
    def checkActionBelongsToAssociatedRole(ActionDsc act){
        var pRole = act.parentRole
        var rs = new ResourceSetImpl()
//DONT KNOW IF THIS IS RIGHT
        var resource = rs.getResource(URI.createURI("./model/generated/Protocol.ecore"), true)
        for(r:resource.allContents.toIterable.filter(typeof(RoleDec))){
            if(r.name == pRole.name){
                //DO SOMETHING
            }
        }
    }
```

In the generator file that I have I already get the Resource object as a parameter.

```
override void doGenerate(Resource resource, IFileSystemAccess fsa) {
        //Generate code
    }
```

How can I do the same thing for my validator. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`act.eResource()` allows to access the resource that contains the action.